# Storing user-input into object in javaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, user-input

I try to store data from user-input in an object in order to be able to store the data in localstorage. My problem is that I cant figure out how to make it work. When I write something as value inside the object (data) it works fine but the user-input cant be stored as value in my object.
Any suggestions?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You should share the relevant code you're using so we can help.

Comment: “but the user-input cant be stored as value in my object” somewhat contradicts “When I write something as value inside the object (data) it works fine”

Answer (score 0):

You can only store [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in localStorage, so you need some way to convert the object to a string first. [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does this.

```
var obj = {};
obj.userInputValue = "Pretend a user entered this";

var objAsString = JSON.stringify(obj);

localStorage.setItem("myObject", objAsString);
```